# .NET App Won't Connect to DB - IIS 8.5 Deployment

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iis-8

I'm adding a new .NET MVC App that runs on the same data model as an older .NET app to IIS 8.5 and for now uses the same connection string for Microsoft SQL Server. It is giving me an error I can't figure out.

Here's the (censored) connection string I'm using for both apps:

```
Data Source=www2.oursite.com;Initial Catalog=*******;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=******;Password=●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Integrated Security=False
```

This is the error I recieve:

> SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details. )

The new app belongs to the same AppPool as the old app, and the directory is granted permissions for that AppPool. I have also tried adding the app to its own AppPool in case that's the issue, and it doesn't seem to change anything.

When I go into the AppPool settings and set **Load User Profile = True**, marvelously, the app runs without any errors. However, it cannot retrieve any items from the database. It's like the database were totally empty.

**Possibly related facts**:

- The apps are two different target runtimes for .NET. The old runs on v4.7.2. The new runs on .NET 5.0.

  - The two apps use the same data model - they are dependent on another .NET Module. The .NET Module runs **EntityFramework v4.0.30319**. The old application uses EntityFramework **v4.0.30319**. The new application uses **EntityFramework v6.44**.
- IIS (Version 8.5) itself is run on Windows Server 2012. (Yes, we pray to upgrade this year.)
- To run these apps on IIS, I package them and move them manually into the webroot, where I then set the settings.
- Both apps run in AppPool where the CLR Version is 4.7.2. Both are set to Integrated.
- When I try loading the new app and it spits out the above error, it takes a long time, like there's a timeout happening when the app tries to connect to the SQL Server.
- I tried setting the AppPool Identity to LocalService, LocalSystem, and NetworkService. Setting to LocalSystem gives me the same error as when I set LoadUserProfile = True -  the app runs, but it's as if it's database queries are returning empty sets of data. The other settings just give the error.

This is all I can think of that might be relevant. Let me know if I can provide more info. I am no expert on this.

Does anyone have any clue? Usually when I'm stuck like this, I can figure it out with some fiddling or come up with a workaround, but I'm so lost here.

**What I've tried**:

- I've granted the AppPool permissions on the project folder.
- I've also tried putting the new app into a different AppPool.
- I've set **UserProfile = True**, got the app running but not retrieving data (see above)
- I tried setting the connection string in web.config, appsettings.json, and in IIS.
- I've made sure the old project and new project have NO differing settings in IIS.
- I've trawled through logs. I've did a looooooot of fiddling.

Comment: This should be a problem with SQL, you can use the same error as a reference: [A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-connection). You can troubleshoot according to the content with this link.

Comment: Can you change "Data Source" to just "Server" and then rest same, and then check?

Comment: Puting .NET Core (ie .NET 5,6,...) in the same process (AppPool) as a .NET Framework app is a bad idea.  .NET Core doesn't support AppDomains, and so each .NET Core app must be in its own AppPool.  Technically it _could_ work to have other .NET Framework apps in the same process, but it's asking for trouble.  And have you installed the ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle on the server? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website&view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Also .NET 5 is out of support.  .NET 6 is the LTS release. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-5-end-of-support-update/